# create map of not null value of an object using java 8 Generic

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I have a model

```
class Foo {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String city;
}
```

setting

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setId(1);
foo.setName("foo test");
```

Now I want a generic method that return not null Map from any object. for example, in case of foo , it return Map that contains `id` and `name`. any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to get this thing done. First convert the foo object into the jsonString using `Gson`. Then pass it to the `ObjectMapper` asking for the map of Json key/value properties. It will filter out null values for you. The code would be something like this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setId(1);
        foo.setName("foo test");

        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        final HashMap<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(gson.toJson(foo),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question clearly, you want a method that operates on your input and provides a map in return. However i am not sure why would you want to do this on a single object. I think you want to operate on list of such objects instead. I am providing answers for single object however you can extend the solution to support lists or arrays as well.

For my first solution, i am not going to use reflection, as it's use in non framework situations for normal production code is discouraged.

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> getGenericMap(Supplier<K> keySupplier, Supplier<V> valueSupplier) {
        Map<K, V> returnMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
        returnMap.put(keySupplier.get(), valueSupplier.get());
        return returnMap;
    }
```

you will have to call above like below:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setId(1);
foo.setName("foo test");
Map<Integer,String> map=getGenericMap(foo::getId,foo::getName);
```

however if you are really inclined towards reflective solution check my **not recommended** solution below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> getGenericMap(Object obj, String keyGetterName, String valueGetterName)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException,
            SecurityException {
        Map<K, V> returnMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
        Class<? extends Object> clazz = obj.getClass();
        Method keyGetter = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(keyGetterName);
        Method valueGetter = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(valueGetterName);
        returnMap.put((K) keyGetter.invoke(obj), (V) valueGetter.invoke(obj));
        return returnMap;
    }
```

the above has to be called like below:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setId(1);
foo.setName("foo test");
Map<Integer,String> map1=getGenericMap(foo, "getId","getName");
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I want to give only object `Map<String`(property name)`,Object `(property value)`> map=getGenericMap(foo);`, it return map of not null value.